# How to stop window from opening up maximized in Ubuntu Mate 17.10

Tags: compiz, ubuntu-mate, maximized

For some reason, whenever I open any application, it opens at full-screen maximization. This applies to everything from Chrome to a small dialog box. Is this a setting in Compiz? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you've enabled maximising new windows in MATE Tweak. Open MATE Tweak, click Windows amnd make sure "Do not auto-maximise new windows" is checked.

Comment: Thanks! worked great, but I had to turn off Compiz first and then re-enable it to have access to it.