# mate-tweak: "window manager is unknown" ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, mate

I want to stop 17.10 from opening windows maximized. I found this answer:

> [How to stop window from opening up maximized in Ubuntu Mate 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976122/how-to-stop-window-from-opening-up-maximized-in-ubuntu-mate-17-10)

So I installed mate-tweak. It only opens with sudo. It reports the message:

```
$sudo mate-tweak
Window Manager is: unknown
Current layout: default
```

It then comes up. I select "Windows". All the "Windows Behavior" options are grayed out and under "Window Manager", it shows "You are currently using an unknown and unsupported window manager. Thus we cannot guarantee that changes made here will be effective"

System originally was 16.04 then upgraded to 17.04 then upgraded to 17.10. Using Wayland.

What "unsupported window manager" am I using?

What else can I do to stop Firefox, in particular, from opening maximized.

FYI: Opening LibreOffice Writer and LibreOffice Impress both open maximized but when I click to make them smaller, they disappear. On the other hand, LibreOffice Calc opens very small.

The problem has nothing to do with the permissions of .config as was suggested:

```
ls -ld .config
drwx------ 40 john john 4096 Jan 23 20:20 .config
```

Answer (score 1):

**marco** is the default window manager for mate-session.

Try installing `sudo apt-get install marco`

and if already installed, then remove it completely and reinstall it.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge marco
sudo apt-get install marco
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `sudo` to run `mate-tweak`.

Usually when started from *System -> Preferences -> Look and Feel -> MATE Tweak* it does not ask for password (no need of `sudo` here).

The problem may be caused by wrong permissions of `~/.config` directory. You can try to restore owner with:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.config
```

Comment: Not a permission problem. I edited the question to show the permissions of .config